# Enforcing image width after upload

Tags: coldfusion

After doing a cffile action="upload", I'd like to check the width (assuming it's a image).  I'm currently using CF8.

Is there a built-in function to get the width of an image?  If there's a built-in function in CF9, I guess I need to know that for when we update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to LiveDocs, the functionality exists in CF8.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_h-im_32.html#5164681

The example provided by Adobe should get you going:

```
<!--- This example shows how to retrieve information associated with the image. --->
<!--- Create a ColdFusion image from a JPEG file.--->
<cfimage source="../cfdocs/images/artgallery/jeff05.jpg" name="myImage">
<!--- Retrieve the information associated with the image. --->
<cfset info=ImageInfo(myImage)>
<cfdump var="#info#"></cfdump>
<p>height = <cfoutput>#info.height#</cfoutput>
<p>width = <cfoutput>#info.width#</cfoutput>
<p>source = <cfoutput>#info.source#"</cfoutput>
```